# How to scroll to the next page with a button event and not gesture in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I want to slide to the next page by a button event instead of scrolling with a gesture.  What I mean by that is, if I were to press the button `Next`, I want the page to be scrolled to the following page.

Following is my code with two pages:

```
export default () => {
    const [animation] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))

    const onPressHandler = () => {
      // this is where I expect the logic should be
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView
                pagingEnabled
                horizontal
                scrollEventThrottle={16}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                onScroll={Animated.event([
                    {
                        nativeEvent: {
                            contentOffset: {
                                x: animation,
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ])}
            >
                <View style={{ width }}>
                    <Text>First Page</Text>
                    <Button title="Next" onPress={onPressHandler} />
                </View>
                <View style={{ width }}>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can scroll directly using `scrollTo` function of `ScrollView` Component,It is quite helpful for maintaining index based scroll position.Use it as below.

```
moveBody = index => {
      this.scrollRef.scrollTo({
        x: index * width,
        animation: false
      })
  }

<ScrollView pagingEnabled ref={node=>this.scrollRef=node}>
 ...
</ScrollView
```

Remember to get correct page make sure the view cover's entire screen width.So that a snap effect can be achieved using next button click.

You can get the index from dividing the offset with the width of the screen.

```
index=e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x/width
```

You can access `e` from `ScrollView` scroll event like `onScroll/onMomentumEnd....`

You can also turn off the scroll gesture by assigning `false` to `scrollEnabled` prop.

Comment: How would I do this in a functional component using useRef?

Comment: @Kevvv - how did you fix this? Could you help please, by providing the code?

Answer (score 2):

Both pagingEnabled and snapToInterval ScrollView behavior are activated by touch and fling events. So they won't be triggered by scrolling programmatically.

Your onPressHandler will have to calculate the correct x value based on the page you want to scroll to, and then call [`scrollTo({x: targetPageX, y: 0, animated: true})`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrollto).

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the advice of `@tvanlaerhoven`.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const _scrollView = createRef();
  }

  nextArrowHandler = page => {

    let gotoPage = 1;
    if (page == 2) {
      gotoPage = 2;
    } else if (page == 3) {
      gotoPage = 3;
    }

    this._scrollView.scrollTo({
      x: width * gotoPage,
      y: 0,
      animated: true
    });
  };
// ...

 <ScrollView
          ref={ref => (this._scrollView = ref)}
// ...
>
<IntroScreenComponent
    nextArrow={this.nextArrowHandler.bind(this, "1")}
// ...

/>
<IntroScreenComponent
    nextArrow={this.nextArrowHandler.bind(this, "2")}
// ...

/>
```

I have 3 `IntroScreenComponent` components in the `ScrollView` and in each component I trigger the `nextArrowHandler` function passing the page `number`, which I then multiply with the `width` of the screen.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your accepted answer I'd like to transform it for `hooks` so it would be easier for users that are new to hooks how to do it:

First, import `useRef` from `react`,
declare your const like:

`const scrollviewRef = useRef()`

Create the function:

```
const moveBody = index => {
      scrollviewRef.current.scrollTo({
        x: index * width,
        animation: false
      })
}
```

And set that variable to your scrollview ref

```
<ScrollView pagingEnabled ref={scrollviewRef}>
 ...
</ScrollView
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:-

```
**let idx = 1;
const scrollRef = React.useRef();
const onPressHandler = () => {
  scrollRef.current.scrollToIndex({index:idx,animated:true});
};**

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
            **ref={scrollRef}**
            pagingEnabled
            horizontal
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            onScroll={Animated.event([
                {
                    nativeEvent: {
                        contentOffset: {
                            x: animation,
                        }
                    },
                    **{
                       useNativeDriver:false,
                       listener: event => {
                         const offsetX = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
                         console.log(offsetX);
                         idx = offsetX/screenWidth;
                         idx += 1;
                       }
                     }**
                }
            ])}
        >
            <View style={{ width }}>
                <Text>First Page</Text>
                <Button title="Next" onPress={onPressHandler} />
            </View>
            <View style={{ width }}>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
)
```